# YA fiction about a pandemic (1990s-2000s) set in a UK new town

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I remember many years ago reading a YA novel about an epidemic or pandemic and the search for a cure. I don't remember much about the plot but I remember the setting extremely well-it was set in a British [new town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_towns_in_the_United_Kingdom), I think it might have been [Milton Keynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton%20Keynes). My guess is it was published some time between 1990 and 2005, probably around 2000. Can anyone help find it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [*Plague*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CGM8DUY) (2001) by Malcolm Rose.

> ‘Who could think of any place more safe and dull than Milton Keynes?
> But as teenagers, Rev, Lucy and Scott while away the summer, an
> invisible enemy is heading their way. Soon the town is in the grip of
> a deadly virus that causes its victims to haemorrhage to death. This
> is not the most literary of novels, but it is a compulsive page turner
> that would grip even the most reluctant reader. It even succeeds in
> making viral science seem sexy, which is no mean feat.’

[image: Cover of "Plague". The cover is largely red, blue, and yellow, with a picture of a microbe.]

Comment: Yes, it is. Magic! How did you find it?

Comment: @Monovox - [Just awesome, I guess.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM).

Comment: I fail to see a SF or fantasy connection in this question

Comment: @DannyMcG - Ah yes, although this is technically a *bacterial* infection, not a virus.

Comment: @DannyMcG it's a fictional story involving epidemiology, which is a science.

Comment: Also, I've been to Milton Keynes and it defies common sense

Comment: I live in MK. You people are rude. :p

Comment: @DannyMcG  What was the fictional date of the novel?  If the fictional date of the novel was before 2020, which is likely, and if it depicts a major plague in the UK which didn't happen in real life before 2020, that is alternate history science fiction.  If the plague strikes in or after 2020 it is science fiction about our future, and if it strikes after 2001 it was science fiction about the writer's future.  If the plague in the story isn't a real known disease the novel is science fiction about an unknown disease.

Comment: I'm suffering from sour grapes because I asked a similar question recently about a book concerning a plague that wiped out a city (America not Milton Keynes) where a doctor had to perform an autopsy on the sidewalk - my question was voted to close because "No SF or Fantasy connection"